# Как использовать get_or_create | api/django

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Помогите с кодом, не понимаю, как это сделать

```
def post_del_recipe(self, request, pk, database):
    recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not database.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                recipe=recipe).exists():
            database.objects.create(
                user=self.request.user,
                recipe=recipe)
            serializer = SubscribeRecipeSerializer(recipe)
            return Response(serializer.data,
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        text = 'errors: Объект уже в списке.'
        return Response(text, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        if database.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                recipe=recipe).exists():
            database.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                recipe=recipe).delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        text = 'errors: Объект не в списке.'
        return Response(text, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    else:
        text = 'errors: Метод обращения недопустим.'
        return Response(text, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что конкретно не понимаете? Документацию читали?

Comment: читал, но ничего не понял, как пользоваться этим

Comment: @Vyacheslav Там есть пример как пользоваться. Пробовали сделать аналогично? Приложите код с попыткой, если пробовали, но не вышло.